# In PivotItem, ListBox Binding dont show value

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, pivotitem

Im create collection for show in **ListBoxTransactions** and binding as **Description**. But in result i have only name collection in **ListBoxTransactions.ItemsSource**, but not value. adn a cant use **ListBox.ItemTemplate**

XAML

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Journal">
      <Grid>
         <ListBox Name="ListBoxTransactions">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="35"/>                            
            </StackPanel>
         </ListBox>
      </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

C#

```
public class TransactHelper
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }        
    }


public void ShowTransactions()
        {
            ListBoxTransactions.Items.Clear();
            var transactFulls = _workerDb.GeTransactFull();
            var list = new List<TransactHelper>();
            foreach (var t in transactFulls)
            {                
                list.Add(new TransactHelper { Description = t.Description });
            }

            this.ListBoxTransactions.ItemsSource = list; // dont view collection. only name collection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement ItemContainerStyle for your items.

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxTransactions" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyItemStyle}">
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="35"/>                            
                      </StackPanel>
                 </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

And once note:
Don't use this pair

```
ListBoxTransactions.Items.Clear();
this.ListBoxTransactions.ItemsSource = list;
```

You need

```
ListBoxTransactions.ItemsSource = null;
this.ListBoxTransactions.ItemsSource = list;
```

Or Implement your collection as ObservableCollection